# Template type not deduced using pointer type

Tags: c++, templates

I was surprised to find that `T` could not be deduced successfully in the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void Set(T* a,T b)
{
    *a = b;
}

void Test()
{
    unsigned long a;
    Set(&a, 1);
}
```

VC++ complains about an ambiguity:

```
1>test.cpp(10): error C2782: 'void Set(T *,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
1>          test.cpp(32) : see declaration of 'Set'
1>          could be 'int'
1>          or       'unsigned long'
```

Obviously this can be fixed by changing the call to `Set(&a, 1ul);` but my question is why is this necessary?

Why can't `T` be deduced using the type of the pointer, which should be unambiguous?

And is there a way to rewrite the template so that the original call to `Set` would compile successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters `T* a` and `T b` are both deduced contexts, so first the compiler will try to deduce `T` from both of them in order to make `T*` *identical to* the type of the first argument and `T` *identical to* to the type of the second argument (following the usual decay adjustments). This yields `unsigned long` from the first argument and `int` from the second, so this attempt at deduction fails.

Then the compiler will attempt to find `T` such that the first argument is *convertible to* `T*` and the second argument is *convertible to* `T` (rather than identical in type). However, in this case only certain conversions are considered. See [temp.deduct.call] in N3936,

> (4) In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced `A`
>   identical to `A` (after the type `A` is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow
>   a difference:
>
> (4.1) — If the original `P` is a reference type, the deduced `A` (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be
>   more cv-qualified than the transformed `A`.
>
> (4.2) — The transformed `A` can be another pointer or pointer to member type that can be converted to the
>   deduced `A` via a qualification conversion (4.4).
>
> (4.3) — If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id,* then the transformed `A` can be a derived class of
>   the deduced `A`. Likewise, if `P` is a pointer to a class of the form *simple-template-id,* the transformed `A`
>   can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced `A`.
>
> (5) These alternatives are considered only if type deduction would otherwise fail. If they yield more than one
>   possible deduced `A`, the type deduction fails. [ *Note:* If a template-parameter is not used in any of the
>   function parameters of a function template, or is used only in a non-deduced context, its corresponding
>   *template-argument* cannot be deduced from a function call and the *template-argument* must be explicitly
>   specified. *— end note* ]

Integer conversions, such as `int` to `unsigned long`, are not considered for parameter types that are in a deduced context. So `T` could not be `unsigned long` in this case, either. Thus, deduction of `T` fails altogether.

My suggestion to fix:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void Set(T* a, U&& b)
{
    *a = std::forward<U>(b);
}
```

Comment: Also, the part starting with "Then the compiler will [..]" seems incorrect. The implementation attempts no further deductions after the first failed attempt. You even show the quote that *excludes* this particular case from the exceptions.

Comment: @Columbo I think this is purely a disagreement about phrasing. I'll edit a bit.

Comment: I would mention the possibility of `std::is_convertible<U,T>::value`, though I'm not sure I would use it here.  `static_assert` is useless here since the only line _is_ the assignment.

Answer (score 6):

> Why can't T be deduced using the type of the pointer, which should be
>   unambiguous?

Because you haven't told the compiler to do so. Inconsistent deductions of a template argument lead to a deduction failure.

> And is there a way to rewrite the template so that the original call
>   to Set would compile successfully?

Yes, using non-deduced contexts.

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {using type=T;};
template <typename T>
using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template <typename T>
void Set(T* a, identity_t<T> b) {
    *a = b;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aabc5cbe0b81187f).
Or use a second template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's ambiguous because it could be both

- `int*` and `int` (because 1 is an `int`)
- `unsigned long*` and `unsigned long` (because your pointer is `unsigned long*`)

Comment: `1` can be ambiguous, but `&a` can't be - it can only be `unsigned long*`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The expression `1` is definitely of type `int`. Always.

Comment: @Columbo Yes but it can be implicitly converted to `unsigned long` which is what would happen in a non-templated function with an `unsigned long` argument.

Comment: I don't think template deduction functionality is (or should be) at liberty to deduce, that it is int `you` want. This would lead to much more problems that it would actually solve.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That makes nothing ambiguous. The deduced type is still always int, completely regardless of what int could be converted to.

Comment: @Columbo I guess I still don't get it; the first parameter can only be a pointer to `unsigned long`, so why doesn't the compiler use that to resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: It could for this case in theory, but in the general case it can't.  C++ prefers you to be explicit in your code rather than guessing at what you probably meant.

Answer (score 0):

The value 1 is deduced to the type `int`, which doesn't match the template argument deduced by `&a`.

> And is there a way to rewrite the template so that the original call
>   to Set would compile successfully

Two parameter way : ( just for *completeness* )

```
#include <type_traits>
// SFINAE : in case S is not convertible to T
template <typename T, typename S,
         typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_convertible<S, T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
void Set(T *a, S b) 
{ 
   *a = b; 
}
```

Comment: If you already use C++11, why not expression SFINAE using decltype?